# ¿Por qué no se me crean las tablas en la base de datos desde Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

¿Alguién sabe por qué? Tengo mi configuración de esta manera

En mi *application.properties*:

```
/**
        spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
        spring.jpa.show-sql=true
        spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
        spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restspring
        spring.datasource.username=root
        spring.datasource.password=root
        **/
```

```
    package com.crudrest.models;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class Persona {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        @Column
        private String nombre;

        @Column
        private String apellido;

        @Column
        private Integer edad;
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Es extraño porque con update debería crearte las tablas. ¿Probaste con spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create? ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: que usas para configurar la construccion de tu proyecto, maven, gradle, o que? que otros archivos de configuracion tienes para la base de datos?